# How to find the installation path of IronPython

Tags: python, ironpython

I have few python scripts of which one is to be executed in IronPython interpreter. How to find the installation path of IronPython. I searched the registry. To my surprise, it was not there.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import sys
print sys.executable
```

Disclaimer: I don't know if it will work on IronPython.

Comment: This works for IronPython 2.0, so presumably "and later" as well

Comment: Does not apply if IronPython.dll is loaded into a 3rd-party program. Even using the DLL path is no good since it can be in the GAC.

Answer (score 1):

From the registry, you can check HKLM\SOFTWARE\IronPython\2.7\InstallPath

It was useful for me.

https://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/34692

Version number can be retrieved like this (as of IPy 2.7.4):

```cs
//Implementation::version backs "sys.version_info"
var version_tuple = new IronPython.Runtime.Implementation().version;
var version = version_tuple.major + "." + version_tuple.minor;
```